# Como deserializar un json a objeto java?

Tags: java, json, archivo

Quiero deserializar JSON a un objeto, tengo el archivo JSON ya creado y tengo una clase clientes que el la clase de la estructura del objeto. Lo que intento hacer aqui es leer el archivo linea a linea con un BufferRider y  pasarlo a una arrayList nueva que he creado.

```
  ArrayList<Cliente> clientes2 =  new ArrayList<>();
    Gson prettyGson = new Gson();
    Cliente cliente;
    BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Clientes.json"));
    String linea = lector.readLine();

    while(linea != null){
        cliente = prettyGson.fromJson(linea, Cliente.class);
        clientes2.add(cliente);
        linea = lector.readLine();
    }
    lector.close();
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

[Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $]

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: @gbianchi claro perdon ahora lo pongo.

Comment: El problema es que tu archivo contiene un array de objetos y tú le estás diciendo que tiene un único objeto. En vez de `Cliente.class` utiliza `Cliente[].class`, además, necesitarás guardarlo en una variable del tipo apropiado claro

Comment: ¿Por qué pasas por Gson línea por línea? Podría funcionar la sugerencia de Benito pero tendrías que mandar el Json completo; lo anterior suponiendo cierta estructura de tu archivo, pero estaría mejor que nos proporciones un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto poniendo un Type con una lista de Clientes porque no lo que tenia en el documento eran varios objetos de Clientes y yo solo intentaba leer uno solo.

```
    BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Tema 6/ControlFicheros/Clientes.json"));
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type tipoListaClientes = new TypeToken<List<Cliente>>(){}.getType();
    List<Cliente> clientes = gson.fromJson(lector, tipoListaClientes);
    for (Cliente cliente : clientes) {
        System.out.println(cliente.toString());
    }
```